# how to fill 3D array with file text in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, javafx-2, javafx-8

i have to fill 3d array with a 3 single array one for day , sec for month , third for year and these 3 single array are initialize and compare them with data in a file text the Question was something like that ;

Create a 3-Dimentional int array to build the seat of the flights. This
array has 5 flights. Each flight has a plane with different rows and columns
based on the Boeing number of the plane. Make sure when you create this array
check the Boeing number to decide the seats. Figure 1 illustrates the structure of
the 3D array and the seats' number and order of each Boeing plane

any help will be appreciated.

int [][][] seat=new int [5][10][5];

```
               Scanner re= new Scanner (input);


               while (re.hasNext()){

                   String crow=re.nextLine();

                       if (crow.equalsIgnoreCase("Book_Seat")){

                           for(int i=0 ; i<seat.length ; i++){

                               for (int j=0 ; j<seat[i].length ; j++){

                                   for(int k=0 ; k<j;k++){

                                   if (seat[i][j][k]==flight_day[i] && seat[i][j][k]==flight_month[j]){
                                       seat[i][j][k]=re.nextInt();

                                       System.out.print(seat[i][j]);
                                   }
                                   }
                                   break;
                               }
                           }
                       }
```

this what arrays should store from the file:

`Book_Seat 01 06 2015
Book_Seat 01 06 2015
Book_Seat 10 06 2015
Book_Seat 05 05 2015
Book_Seat 23 07 2015
Print_Flight_Status`

Comment: Can you share the figure? I'm confused about the structure of this array. An array cannot have different sizes for a dimension

Comment: @Oneiros i tried to, but i didn't know how to post it

Comment: Please format your code, it is very hard to read